# How to get the start_time of the last completed job in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-job-monitoring

Suppose these are my job runs:

```
job_id | job_status
-------------------
1        COMPLETED
2        COMPLETED
3        FAILED
4        COMPLETED
5        FAILED
```

Now during the runtime of **job 6**, I want to find out the **start_time** of the *last successfully completed job* i.e. **job 4**

How can I get it?

I tried using the `JobExplorer` API but it gives output based on input `count`

This will not work for me if there is a COMPLETED job followed by 10 FAILED jobs. I will not get the COMPLETED job then.

```java
List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances("myJob", 0, 10);

Optional<JobInstance> lastCompletedJobInstance =
jobInstances.stream()
            .filter(jobInstance -> {
                long instanceId = jobInstance.getInstanceId();
                return BatchStatus.COMPLETED == jobExplorer.getJobExecution(instanceId).getStatus();
             })
            .findFirst();
```

The reason why I need is because in my `ItemReader`, I want to fetch delta records from my database using a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM items i WHERE i.created_at >= :lastSuccessfulJobRun
```

I don't want to manually query Batch tables like `batch_job_execution`, `batch_job_execution_context` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to eventually write a SQL query myself:

```
SELECT job_execution_id, start_time, end_time, status
FROM
batch_job_execution
WHERE
job_instance_id IN (SELECT job_instance_id FROM batch_job_instance WHERE job_name = :jobName)
AND 
status = :status
ORDER BY job_execution_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```